# Extra space after the figure or table caption

Tags: captions, naming

I want to change figures and table naming from `Figure 1` to `Figure S1` and analogously for tables. I tried to use:

```
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Figure S}
```

or

```
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figure S}
```

but what I get in these cases is `Figure S 1`. I don't want that extra space between `S` and figure/table number. How can I get rid of that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use

```
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Figure}
\captionsetup[table]{name=Table}
\renewcommand\thefigure{S\arabic{figure}}
\renewcommand\thetable{S\arabic{table}}
```

Maybe that Figure and Table are already the predefined names. Then you do need the first two lines.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want that the “S” is part of the cross references, you can add it to the figure name:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}

\DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{nospace}{#1#2}
\captionsetup[figure]{name={Figure S},labelformat=nospace}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\fbox{placeholder}

\caption{A label\label{test}}

\end{figure}

See figure~\ref{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]